# Google Safety net addOnFailureListener not trigger when user dismiss the verify dialog

Tags: android, sdk, recaptcha, safetynet

**Note** I posted the issue/question to [google sample github repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-safetynet), https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-safetynet/issues/12. However, I don't get any response yet.

**library version used:** com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.4.2

I am using [safety net captcha API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha.html). everything working as expected meaning, both are detected:
- on success (when test with real device and no harms detected) 
- one failure listener (when test with Android emulator and verified the steps)

**However, Here steps produce issue where on success and on failure are not detected:**
- Run app in Android emulator
- Hit the SafetyNet verify with captcha
- As android emulator mark as possible harm, it will shows image for the verification
- Click on listen icon to listen the word
- Click on the screen outside the dialog area, the verification dialog will close

**Expected:** addOnFailureListener should be triggered because user didn't response to the verification steps when detected as robot

**Actual:** both OnSuccessListener and addOnFailureListener are not detected

**Sample code**

```
SafetyNet.getClient(this).verifyWithRecaptcha(YOUR_API_SITE_KEY)
            .addOnSuccessListener((Executor) this,
            new OnSuccessListener<SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse response) {
                    // Indicates communication with reCAPTCHA service was
                    // successful.
                    String userResponseToken = response.getTokenResult();
                    if (!userResponseToken.isEmpty()) {
                        // Validate the user response token using the
                        // reCAPTCHA siteverify API.
                    }
                }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener((Executor) this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    if (e instanceof ApiException) {
                        // An error occurred when communicating with the
                        // reCAPTCHA service. Refer to the status code to
                        // handle the error appropriately.
                        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
                        int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + CommonStatusCodes
                                .getStatusCodeString(statusCode));
                    } else {
                        // A different, unknown type of error occurred.
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        });
```

**Questions:**

- Is it expected design in which if user dismiss the verification dialog then SafetyNet doesn't notify the listener?
- Are there any other listener for SafetyNet to handle the scenario above of the issue? or other solutions to handling this scenario from SafetyNet SDK?

Thanks

Comment: did you find any solution on this?

Comment: pls refer to this created issue https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-safetynet/issues/12

Comment: can you put your solution an answer so people can find it here only.

Answer (score 0):

Github issue solution is to handle action onResume()

When safety net captcha is Cancelled:
In my case requirement were to end animation on button when safety net captcha was dismissed. So user would be able to click on it once again.

When safety net captcha fails:
They suggested to close all dialog onResume()

In Kotlin answer for that should be:

```
supportFragmentManager.fragments.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.map { (it as? DialogFragment)?.dismiss() }
```

For java you can find answer here:
[Android - How to Dismiss All Dialogs in onPause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201701/android-how-to-dismiss-all-dialogs-in-onpause)